# Android: start activity from opengl rendererr

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-activity

I'm developing game and i'm trying to start an activity that shows players score and button for restart game, when player fail or complete level, but it throws NullPointerException. Here is my code. what's wrong with it.

```
    public class MyRenderer extends Activity implements Renderer {
    @Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
       ...............
       if(..............) startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.RESTART"));
       ...............
       }
    }


    <activity
        android:name=".Restart"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.RESTART" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 2):

startActivity() is available in Activity. GLSurfaceView is a View.

Try this:

```
public class YourRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer{
.....
.....
private Context mContext;

public YourRenderer(Context context){
mContext = context;
}

public onDrawFrame(Gl10 gl){
if(some statement){
Intent intent = new Intent(...);
mContext.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Method onDrawFrame work in thread GLThread. You can't start Activity from non UI thread.